# how reduce API calls between microservices spring boot

Tags: caching, apache-kafka, microservices

I have two spring boot microservices say `qbank` and `reports`. For communication I am using API calls.

Problem - In a `repots` function I need some data from `qbank`, but the function is being called so frequently because of heavy user traffic.

`qbank` data does not changes so frequently, may be in a month manually by Admins.

So how can I reduce the API calls ? Solutions that I thought -

1. Cache - Problem - how to keep updated ? Need to modify very fast just after `qbank` data changes. (API call from `qbank` to `reports` not allowed)
2. Kafka - Don't know much about it but can it helps ? if yes then how ?

Any suggestion will be welcomed.

Comment: https://www.mitrais.com/news-updates/asynchronous-communication-between-microservices-with-apache-kafka/

Comment: Is each report different?

Answer (score 1):

> qbank data does not changes so frequently, may be in a month manually by Admins

**CDC (Change data Capture) on qbank data with Kafka Connect**

One of the choice is to have copy of qbank data in reports database.

Kafka Connect can be used to to monitor qbank data and detect any changes happen on qbank data (Source) and replicate the same into reports database (Sink).

- Source Connector (qbank database)
- Sink Connector (reports database)

**Cache** can be one more option in Microservices to share data across services but picking right caching mechanism/strategies depends on various factors.

- Caching strategies
- Eviction policy
- Data access strategies
- Data type wise Cache
  etc..